# How can I implement this bivariate sign test in R?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, nonparametric

Suppose $(X_1,Y_1),(X_2,Y_2),\ldots,(X_n,Y_n)$ are i.i.d with a common continuous bivariate distribution function $F$. I wish to test $H_0:(\mu_1,\mu_2)=(0,0)$ against $H_1: (\mu_1,\mu_2)\ne (0,0)$, where $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are the unique medians of $X$ and $Y$.

Define $T_1$ as the number of pairs $(X,Y)$ with $X\le 0,Y\le 0\,$; $T_2$ as the number of pairs with $X> 0,Y> 0$; and $T_3$ as the number of pairs such that $X\le 0,Y> 0$. Also let $T_C=T_1+T_2$.

When $T_C\ne 0,n$, Chatterjee's bivariate sign test statistic for testing $H_0$ is

$$T=\frac{\left(T_1-\frac{T_C}{2}\right)^2}{T_C/4}+\frac{\left(T_3-\frac{n-T_C}{2}\right)^2}{(n-T_C)/4}$$

It is known that under $H_0$, given $T_C=t_c\,$, $T_1\sim \text{Bin}\left(t_c,\frac12\right)$ and $T_3\sim \text{Bin}\left(n-t_c,\frac12\right)$ are conditionally independent. This makes $T$ conditionally distribution free under $H_0$ given $T_C$.

And an exact size $\alpha$ test is of the form

$$\varphi(T,T_C)=\mathbf1_{\{T>d\}}+\gamma \mathbf1_{\{T=d\}}\,,$$

where $d=d(t_c)$ and $\gamma=\gamma(t_c)$ are such that $$E_{H_0} \left[\varphi\mid T_C=t_c\right]=\alpha\,.$$

I am trying to implement the above test in `R`. So I generated $n=20$ observations from a bivariate normal distribution and calculated the observed value $t$ of my test statistic. I have got $t_c=13$ and $t=9.8$. Now taking $\alpha=0.05$, I have to find $d$ and $\gamma$ such that $$P_{H_0}(T>d\mid T_C=t_c)+\gamma P_{H_0}(T=d\mid T_C=t_c)=0.05$$

But looks like I need to find, for example (taking some choices of $d$), $$P\left(\frac{4\left(T_1-\frac{13}{2}\right)^2}{13}+\frac{4\left(T_3-\frac{7}{2}\right)^2}{7}>d\right)$$

and see if this probability exceeds $0.05$ or not. Here $T_1\sim \text{Bin}\left(13,\frac12\right)$ and $T_3\sim \text{Bin}\left(7,\frac12\right)$ are independent. There is similar calculation if I try to find the p-value for my test. The exact details are a little cumbersome to work out by hand. Is there a way to do this in `R` or am I approaching this in the wrong way?